# NativeScript-audio problem in changing the music track

Tags: javascript, audio, nativescript, nativescript-vue

With reference to code at
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=nBDUXH&v=3

I am trying to play an audio file with nativescript-audio plugin. I am able to do it with one music track.

Now I want to change the music track on click event  (@tap on label). But it looks like player is not considering the change in media path once it played a track. Code is not generating any logs which can help.

Comment: `initFromUrl` returns a promise, you are suppose to wait for the promise to resolve. You are calling play method too early, move all your code too page loaded event and call play once the promise is resolved. Also destroy the player when you are done Or keep one player instance centrally.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Manoj or pointing out my mistake. After following you it worked.
Instead of calling play method on page load now i called it once promise is resolved.